# Custom view in xpages

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Is it possible to create view like below in xpages. If yes, how? Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Sure, for instance using repeats and CSS

Comment: Thanks. If I use repeats, Will I be able to use pager as well? (Like in views)

Comment: Yes. I am able to add pager. Thanks a lot for ur suggestion.

Comment: Just confirming: yes you can use a pager for a repeat

Comment: David Leedy has some nice videos on Repeat controls. It's at notesin9.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed possible. You can use a repeat and then add CSS to style your elements within each row.

After all, what you are targetting is "just" HTML and CSS. So you can do that with XPages too.

Comment: This project includes a repeat that looks almost identical to what you're targeting: http://openntf.org/p/elenchus